# Can (how) one distinguish germs of continuous functions by a countable set of params?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, set-theory, real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

Continuous functions can be distinguished by their values at say rational points of [0 1].
Germs of analytic functions can be distinguished by derivatives at a point. 
So in both cases we see countable sets of "parameters" for out set.

Consider set of germs of continuous functions.

**Question:** Is there a countable set of parameters such that different germs have different values of params ?

If yes, is there any "nice" set of parameters ? Or one may prove existence, but impossible to construct them "constructively / explicitly" ?

---

Related question: ["Nice" functions on germs of continuous functions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/184768/nice-functions-on-infinite-dimensional-space-of-germs-of-continuous-functions).
My informal question is: "How to thing of germs of continuous functions/
what are "coordinates" on that space ? ".
Any informal comments are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

The way I view it, germs of continuous functions are like

- tails of infinite binary sequences, or
- real numbers up to rational translation.

Finding "coordinates" on the space of germs would be like finding an explicit [Vitali set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set).

Possible using the Axiom of Choice, but not in any explicit way.

Comment: Thank you ! First sentence : analytic - you mean continuous?

Comment: Thanks for adding the relevant tags Bjørn! Right now, I only have time for my daily sweep of MO but the relevant keywords are $E_0$ and [Borel equivalence relations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_equivalence_relation).

Comment: Yes, and because $E_0$ is a minimal degree above smooth, it suffices to show that this equivalence is not smooth.

Comment: It seems you are saying that germs are isomorphic as a ring to tails of sequences with additional requirement that sequences should have a limit. Indeed, take x_n->0 and map a function to its values f(x_n), passing to germs corresponds to tails. Correct ? What is the role of AC ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov we can look at the values $f(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb Q$, $x$ close to $0$, to determine the germ of $f$ at 0. But to pick out one *and only one* representative of *each* germ requires choice

Comment: Why do we need to choose representative ?

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Well otherwise you might as well take any continuous function as parameter for its germ.. or weave its values together into a single real number

Comment: Germs = function/equivalence relation. It seems to me we can choose representative by definition - choose an a element in subset of equivalent functions. What is wrong ? And yes, it gives answer to my question, of course, it is not the anwer I hoped to, but formally it is an answer. I'll think how to modify my question to avoid this answer, but let me do it later...

Comment: Remark. It seems to me fractal dimension is "nice" function on germs. But it seems you say that there are NO "nice" functions on germs (AC is necessary).... Some contradiction in my head

Comment: @AlexanderChervov Re: "choose representative by definition": this works as long as you're only considering one germ, but if considering all germs it requires AC.

Comment: @AlexanderChervov So maybe what you want to ask is, if we consider all possible properties $P$ such as fractal dimension, differentiability, etc., then do these determine the germ? Perhaps if the collection of such properties $\mathcal P$ is complicated then there is no way to *given $\mathcal P$ construct a germ satisfying all members of $\mathcal P$*, without choice. In which case, maybe you could find a description of $\mathcal P$ without choice. Interesting...

Comment: Function on germs: IF germ has derivative, then F(germ)=derivative, ELSE zero. This function seems to me quite "nice" and "constructive". Seems we do not need AC to define it. In contrast to your another example - "reals/rational translation" - it seems to me for that example there is NO "nice" function at all, is it correct ?  So may be these two examples are different ? Pay attention that germs correspond to tail of sequences which have limit - may be property of having limit change something...